# Why do message sampling processors stop probing messages?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

in one of my wso2 environments I have a problem with message sampling processors which from time to time stop gathering messages from queues.

We have around 60 message processors and often after environment restart or after deployment some of them just stops, and restart working after several minutes, sometimes hours. There are no errors in wso2carbon.log. Last logs about these processors are the ones that they have started :(

I think this may have something to do with some kind of a resource limit on this environment, because it only effects one environment.

Here's a sample code for message processor and it's message store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor
  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor"
  messageStore="ms_notifyOfDocumentChangeOut_getDocument"
  name="mp_notifyOfDocumentChangeOut_getDocument" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
  <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
  <parameter name="client.retry.interval">0</parameter>
  <parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
  <parameter name="sequence">s_notifyOfDocumentChangeOut_queue_getDocument</parameter>
  <parameter name="concurrency">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore"
  name="ms_notifyOfDocumentChangeOut_getDocument" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.failover.message.store.name">ms_notifyOfDocumentChangeOut_getDocument</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.jms.destination">ms_notifyOfDocumentChangeOut_getDocument</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

Any ideas which resources are required for it to work correctly?
I've suspected max-threads, but..

cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

62735

Comment: Have you configured lst_t_core, lst_t_max for the jms part ?

Comment: Can You point me to the configuration file where these are set?

Comment: wso2esb-4.9.0\repository\conf\nhttp.properties ? Is nhttp used in message processors?

Comment: not http, but jms. By default, the ESB (4.8.1, but this is probably the same with 4.9) try to load a file named ESB_HOME/conf/jms.properties. Try with this content : lst_t_core=50
lst_t_max=100
snd_t_core=50
snd_t_max=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring lst_t_core, lst_t_max in jms.properties worked. Thank You Jean-Michel :)